# Editing an existing input .val() without effecting the other input val()'s

Tags: jquery

This is going to be a no brainer for most of you, but I cant track or think what to do to solve this issue I am having. Take a look here **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ykPNQ/1/)**

In this function it should edit the value of the input and only send to that input, its like in my code `el` refers to all the elements that have been clicked.

I think the code explains my angle, ill paste some jQuery here, if you need more just ask.

```
var app = {

sendEditDataToApp: function (el) {

    //Type of element to send
    var elType = jQuery(el).prev().attr('name')

    //Element data
    var elVal = jQuery(el).prev().val()

    //Match the edit element with the element constructor
    var inConstructor = jQuery(el).closest('.display-data').prev()

    inConstructor.addClass('opened')

    //Send to app
    jQuery('.builder .send').click(function () {

        //Set new data input value
        jQuery(el).parent().find('input').val(inConstructor.find(this).prev().val())
        alert(inConstructor.find(this).prev().val())

        inConstructor.removeClass('opened')

    });


}

}

jQuery('.open').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    app.sendEditDataToApp(this)
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="builder">
    <input value="" />
    <button class="send">Send</button>
</div>

<div class="display-data">  
<div class="row"> 
<input name="html" value="input 1" />
<button class="open">Open</button>
</div>

<div class="row"> 
<input name="html" value="input 2" />
<button class="open">Open</button>
</div>

<div class="row"> 
<input name="html" value="input 3" />
<button class="open">Open</button>
</div>  
</div>
```

My code is getting the `.val()` of the input, I am not sure why its adding to all the inputs when I thought using `this` and `el` would only refer to the specific input the click came from.

Mind you, I rewrote this code to suit a better fiddle, its based on logic of my real code, some was copied and pasted from my real code, most was re-edited. The main goal is to edit the specific input the open click came from.

I would say the main thing to focus on is `jQuery(el).parent().find('input').val(inConstructor.find(this).prev().val())`

(WARNING: this may be an incorrect statement, my logic here) `el` refers to the first element `.open`, and `this` refers to the `.send`. I find the specific input in which the `.open` click came from, then set that value to be whatever is inside the  `inConstructor` value upon click of `this` `.send`. So to me it should get the value of the input and place it in the specific `jQuery(el).parent().find('input')` <- not all of the ones that have been clicked.

Comment: I think I know what to do now.. I need to add an active class. And send it to the active input.

Comment: Ok I got it.. writing that fiddle and asking this definitely made me analyze the code better.. I needed to add a class like `.edit` then instead of `jQuery(el).parent` I would write this `jQuery(el).closest('.edit')` works like a charm

Comment: This is a work around and not a solution for your problem. The problem is that on multiple clicks you have too many events that are fired.

Comment: Thanks ill take a look at this in a bit, I appreciate the effort to make my code better ill figure out what I can improve by looking at your code.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
var app = {

    sendEditDataToApp: function (el) {

        //Type of element to send
        var elType = jQuery(el).prev().attr('name')

        //Element data
        var elVal = $(el).prev().val()

        //Match the edit element with the element constructor
        var inConstructor = $(el).closest('.display-data').prev()

        inConstructor.addClass('opened')

        //Send to app
        $('.builder .send').click(function (ev) {
            //Set new data input value
            $(el).parent().find('input').val(inConstructor.find(this).prev().val())
            alert(inConstructor.find(this).prev().val())            
            inConstructor.removeClass('opened');
            $(this).unbind('click');
            return false;

        });


    }

}

jQuery('.open').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    app.sendEditDataToApp(this);
    return false;
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykPNQ/3/)